# Is there any way to prevent memory leak when using exit( ) function?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
class A
{
public:
    unique_ptr<int> m_pM;
    A() { m_pM = make_unique<int>(5); };
    ~A() { };
public:
    void loop() { while (1) {}; } // it means just activating some works. for simplifying
};

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    A a;
    a.loop(); // if i use force quit while activating this function, it causes memory leak

}
```

Assuming only memory leaks detected by VS macros.
i think there are no way to prevent memory leak if i use exit() in the loop.
because exit() doesnt call destructor so unique_ptr cant free his allocated memory.

Am I correct? or is there some other way to call destructor when use exit()?

Comment: if by force quit you mean using Ctrl+C (in terminal, or closing the app by other means) most common operating systems will indeed take back the memory they gave to the process.

Comment: Don't force-quit the program when you are using the memory leak checker? Force-quit is force-quit, and obviously the program isn't going to free all the memory first before it quits... The OS still frees the memory when the program quits, so it's fine.

Comment: @AlexVask but Visual Studio compiler said Detected memory leaks <- i want to avoid this

Comment: @asdf as per my answer, the compiler takes the infinite loop quite literally, and rightfully so. The Visual Studio leak checker will indeed try to catch leaks @ program runtime and here it will be right to detect one. To NOT leak the resources, you *have to* end the loop properly, and not via force quitting. You could use a condition of some sort as a stopping criteria and loop while(!condition) {…}

Answer (score 4):

`a.loop()` is an infinite loop so everything after that is unreachable, so the compiler is within its right to remove all code after the call to `a.loop()`. See the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MxTxb4xae) for proof.

Comment: I think it's even UB to have infinite loop in the program, program must be possible to end in some way.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes infinite loops without side effects are UB https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 0):

I believe that outside of some niche and very rare scenarios truly infinite loops like the one you wrote here are pretty useless, since they literally mean “loop indefinitely”. So what’s the compiler supposed to do? In some sense it just postpones the destruction of your object until some infinite time in the future.
What you usually do is use `break` inside such loop and break when some condition is met. A simplified example: https://godbolt.org/z/sxr7eG4W1
Here you can see the unique_ptr::default_delete in the disassembly and also see that the compiler is actually checking the condition inside the loop.
Note: extern volatile is used to ensure the compiler doesn’t optimise away the flag, since it’s a simplified example and the compiler is smart enough to figure out that the flag is not changed. In real code I’d advice against using volatile. Just check for the stop condition. That’s it.